# Cannot configure new SQL view

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql

I created in Geoserver a store by using a PostGIS database (PostgreSQL 9.6) and I have some tables with geospatial data. When I add a new layer I cannot see the link 'Create new feature type' anymore. What am I missing?

I use Windows 10 x64, Geoserver 2.11.0, PostgreSQL 9.6.2 by BigSQL, PostGIS 2.3.

Comment: what's in the log file?

Comment: I found this line: `2017-05-15 09:15:30,396 WARN [geoserver.catalog] - Error while getting feature type, flushing cache and retrying: Unknown type references` 
'references' is an already existing view!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that a new created table was a problem for the Geoserver. This table needs quotation marks which confused the Geoserver. My solution is to use table names without quotation marks.